# eBay API - check Finding API calls count?

Tags: ebay-api

Thanks to that page: https://go.developer.ebay.com/api-call-limits we know that eBay allows up to 5000 requests per day per ebay developer account. 
But - maybe somebody know - it is possible to check current usage (requests count) and usage history of that limit ?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this situation myself, and made a note to come back and answer this with the available options I found once I got my own API call limit exceeded errors resolved with the eBay developers program.

Monitor the limit in code) You can crudely monitor your daily usage against the 5000 per day limit using another eBay API - GetAPIAccessRules https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetApiAccessRules.html

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetApiAccessRulesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>ABC...123</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
</GetApiAccessRulesRequest>
```

Monitor the daily limit manually) You can more precisely check the API usage in your developer dashboard manually and determine how you are doing here - https://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/account/default.aspx

Just click on "API Reports" under either production or sandbox API sections to view the usage for a given time period.

Just raise the limit) You can submit and pass the eBay API compatibility check with your app and get the 5000 per day limit raised to up to 1.5M calls per day.   That process is described here - https://go.developer.ebay.com/compatible-application-check-and-checklist-going-live

This eBay developer technical support link may help also - https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=439