# ebay The API call "ApplicationAggregate" is invalid or not supported in this release error

Tags: php, ebay-api

I need to get ebay api limit usage in my application. I am trying to use the code from this post [eBay API - check Finding API calls count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786145/ebay-api-check-finding-api-calls-count)

Here is my code sample:

```
function getEbayApiUsage(){
    $ebayCredentials = $this->getEbayCredentials();   
    $token = $ebayCredentials['token'];  
    $XMLData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <GetApiAccessRulesRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
          <RequesterCredentials>
            <eBayAuthToken>'.$token.'</eBayAuthToken>
          </RequesterCredentials>
        </GetApiAccessRulesRequest>';
        $reults = $this->callEbayAPI($XMLData, "ApplicationAggregate");
        return $reults;
}    
function callEbayAPI($XMLData, $APICallName) {
    $COMPATIBILITYLEVEL = $this->COMPATIBILITYLEVEL;
    $DEVNAME = $this->DEVNAME;
    $APPNAME = $this->APPNAME;
    $CERTNAME = $this->CERTNAME;
    $SiteId = $this->SiteId;
    $eBayAPIURL = $this->eBayAPIURL; 
    $header = array(
        "X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL: $COMPATIBILITYLEVEL",
        "X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME: $DEVNAME",
        "X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME: $APPNAME",
        "X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME: $CERTNAME",
        "X-EBAY-API-SITEID: $SiteId",
        "X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME: " . $APICallName
    );    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $eBayAPIURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $XMLData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);    
    return $results;
}
```

And I am getting this error :

> Unsupported API call.The API call "ApplicationAggregate" is invalid or
>   not supported in this release.2ErrorRequestError92318451796

Can you please help me to get the api usage limit?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the line:

```
$reults = $this->callEbayAPI($XMLData, "ApplicationAggregate");
```

*callEbayAPI* is expecting the name of the API operation that you want to call. In this instance you are calling *GetApiAccessRules*. The correct code should be:

```
$reults = $this->callEbayAPI($XMLData, "GetApiAccessRules");
```